# MouseHover doesn't work with OnMouseOver method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, grid, onmouseover, mousehover

In my game in Unity i have to spawn a sprite above a cell in the grid when the mouse goes over it. I've tried using the OnMouseOver method and the BoxCollider2D, but it doesn't work.

This is my current script for the Cell GameObject:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

[RequireComponent(typeof(BoxCollider2D))]

public class CellManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    void OnMouseEnter()
    {
        //Code (that doesn't execute)
    }

    void OnMouseExit()
    {
        //Code
    }

}
```

I've learnt a lot about it, i've tried usign EventTrigger and set 'both' on Input System (project settings), with the same result. I've heard about Raycasting and other things but i don't know anything about it and i don't know what i have to do exactly.

Comment: well, you dont need both unless you use both, and if you use new, you can change the eventsystem to work with the new, from memory it realises its the wrong one and offers a button i think to change it.. or you're using the old one.. in which case dont enable the new if you dont use it.. TBH the raycasting was going to be my guess - i dont do much in 2d, but certainly in 3d you need physics raycaster on the camera... but im pretty sure its all documented on unitys website

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***Event Trigger*** Component.

[image: Event Trigger Component]

[image: Grid Cell]

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRiHc.gif)

You have to disable Raycast Target checkbox of hover image if you want to show hover image above a cell.

[image: Hover Image]

Hope help you my answer .